# xpath query to update an element by value

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to access an element by value using an XPath query for later update its value, although the XML file is simple, failed to get find the right query.

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <OBJECTID>1</OBJECTID>
    <TABLE_PK>IN</TABLE_PK>
    <FIELD_PK>AC_TR_OID</FIELD_PK>
    <TABLE_FK></TABLE_FK>
  </row>
  <row>
    <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID>
    <TABLE_PK>ARQUETAP</TABLE_PK>
    <FIELD_PK>ARP_AR_OID</FIELD_PK>
    <TABLE_FK>ARQ</TABLE_FK>
  </row>
  <row>
    <OBJECTID>3</OBJECTID>
    <TABLE_PK>ACOMRUR</TABLE_PK>
    <FIELD_PK>ACR_TR_OID</FIELD_PK>
    <TABLE_FK>PASS</TABLE_FK>
  </row>
  <row>
    <OBJECTID>4</OBJECTID>
    <TABLE_PK>ACOMRUR</TABLE_PK>
    <FIELD_PK>ACR_RA_OID</FIELD_PK>
    <TABLE_FK>WRANCH</TABLE_FK>
  </row>
  <row>
    <OBJECTID>5</OBJECTID>
    <TABLE_PK>ACTUATION</TABLE_PK>
    <FIELD_PK>ACT_ACTUATIONP_OID</FIELD_PK>
    <TABLE_FK>ACTUATIONP</TABLE_FK>
  </row>
</root>
```

I just want to get access elements one by one, for example:
Update TABLE_PK element called ACOMRUR the number row 3 with a new value to replace ACOMRUR, 
/root/row[3]/OBJETID[text()='ACOMRUR']
/root/row/TABLE_PK[text()='ACOMRUR']

I also tested with more complex queries, nested,logical operators but nothing.
I would appreciate any suggestions
thanks,

Comment: /root/row[3]/OBJETID[text()='ACOMRUR']

Comment: /root/row/TABLE_PK[text()='ACOMRUR']

Comment: You may need to provide [prefixes/mappings or brace URI literals](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-basics) for the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but you may use following xpath :

`/root/row/*`

this will return all the immediate child elements of all the `rows` in the `root` element.